# URI issue in Servlets mapping filter

Tags: servlets

I want to get my page not mapping url web.xml file.Here is my ancher tag

```
**<a href="/name">Click here</a>**


   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>demoData</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>  </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>demoData</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/name</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

If i using this  **requet.getRequetURI();** then i got /**name** in url not getting **/index.jsp**.
I want to get /index.jsp when we will access /name url.

Answer (score 0):

The `requet.getRequetURI()` is returning the expected. I don't think there is anything available in servlet API to accomplish your requirement. But you can work around by adding the jsp name in the `<init-param>` of servlet context or by parsing the web.xml.

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>/name</param-name>
 <param-value>/index.jsp</param-value>
</context-param>


ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
String paramValue = context.getInitParamter("/name");
```

Comment: Ok thanks for reply but this is not suitable process for url filtration in servlet filter.

Comment: True, I did realize that. Thought I deleted the answer, my bad. However, you could consider filter init-parm in your case and use FilterConfig.getInitParameter().